# How do I derive the cubic formula? (without substitutions)

Tags: polynomials, problem-solving, cubics

I've heard of a number of ways that people have derived a cubic formula (I've even heard of a number of different ways to show the formula itself too). What I want to know is how to derive it without any substitutions (like the wikipedia article on it). I know it will be messy, but at least I'll be able to understand it better.

More specifically, I want to know how to solve it without using such complex methods that everyone seems to be using, and don't just link to wolfram (you could link to another step-by-step solver that's free though).

$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$

...

$x=?$

Comment: Why, you may just ask [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ax^3%2Bbx^2%2Bcx%2Bd%3D0), it knows the exact form you are after (not that it did anyone any good, though).

Comment: Is your objection to *complex* methods or *complicated* methods?  Substitution actually reduces the complication

Comment: @Henry My objection is against the advanced symbols and substitutions, I don't care about how big and messy the process will be.

Comment: see here http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/